# Insert date from two tables in MySql

Tags: mysql

Consider the following two table

```
Table A:
id int auto_increment

with 2 rows of data.
id
1
2

Table B:
id auto_increment
aid reference to A.id

with 3 rows of data
id  aid 
1    1
2    2
3    2
```

If now the table A has been inserted 2 rows to

```
Table A:
id
1
2
3
4
```

So, how to write the insert statement so that it can insert to table B as result

```
Table B:
id  aid
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    4
7    5
8    6
9    6
```

The question is for study only. I know there are many ways to do it, but I am just wondering if it can be done by using sql or just in mysql?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, the question since to be unclear. Let me state it in clear.

1. The data in table B has relation to table A. B.aid = A.id
2. The new data in table A, which is A.id, are in sequence, also has relation to the first two id. That means 1 and 3 with the same meaning, 2 and 4 also.
3. In the insertion of table B, it should consider both 1. and 2. That means, since with one aid=1 and two aid=2, then the data that needs to insert into table B is one aid=3, two aid=4, one aid=5 and two aid=6.

The question: This can be done easily with programming, however, I just wondering can 3. be done in a insert statement with out programming in Mysql?

Comment: What is the logic behind the data that is to be inserted on table B ?

Comment: You want even IDs to be inserted twice, or what is the question?

Comment: @AdrianBR Thanks for your comment, I have updated the question.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thanks you chak, I have updated the question

Comment: @PandaYang I still don't understand the logic of the insert. odd values once and twice for those that divide by 2? Or does it need to dynamically follow any pattern of 1 and 2s in B? And where did the 5 and 6 come from, you only have 1,2,3,4 in  A, so do extra values get generated based on some rule?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are inserting the ID(s) into Table A,

```
INSERT INTO [Table B](aid) VALUES ([THE ID])
```

Where this will insert the specified ID, in the aid column in Table B.

Otherwise if you want to match up the values you can use NOT IN to detect values that are not like, then you must insert these values,
This will select all IDs that do not exist in Table B:

```
SELECT id
FROM [Table A]
WHERE [Table A].id Not In (SELECT aid FROM [Table B])
```

...then later (depending what you're using it in, PHP? Then fletch the data (should look something like this))...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(...))
{
   INSERT INTO [Table B](aid) VALUES($row['aid'])
}
```